# why i am getting javax.ws.rs.WebApplicationException

Tags: eclipse, web-services, apache-tomee

I'm trying to code a simple project. I am using `tomee`. Tomee is working fine, but I can not reach to my project. When I try to go my project from the browser, eclipse console gives me the following error.

```
INFO: Server startup in 1661 ms
Dec 11, 2013 7:59:15 PM org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.interceptor.JAXRSInInterceptor processRequest
WARNING: No root resource matching request path  has been found, Relative Path: /. Please enable FINE/TRACE log level for more details.
Dec 11, 2013 7:59:15 PM org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.impl.WebApplicationExceptionMapper toResponse
WARNING: javax.ws.rs.WebApplicationException
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.interceptor.JAXRSInInterceptor.processRequest(JAXRSInInterceptor.java:162)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.interceptor.JAXRSInInterceptor.handleMessage(JAXRSInInterceptor.java:91)
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:262)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.ChainInitiationObserver.onMessage(ChainInitiationObserver.java:121)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.AbstractHTTPDestination.invoke(AbstractHTTPDestination.java:237)
    at org.apache.openejb.server.cxf.rs.CxfRsHttpListener.onMessage(CxfRsHttpListener.java:170)
    at org.apache.openejb.server.rest.RsServlet.service(RsServlet.java:53)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.OpenEJBValve.invoke(OpenEJBValve.java:45)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1041)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:603)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems rest services take over your complete context if you don't specify an Application, so add the class below to your context and it should work (it worked for me).

```java
@ApplicationPath("/rest") 
public class ApplicationConfig extends Application { 
}
```

http://openejb.979440.n4.nabble.com/No-root-resource-matching-request-path-td4666495.html

**UPDATE**

Alternatively, in order not to have the ugly `/rest` part in your rest urls: Instead of specifying `urlPatterns={"/*"}` for your main web application (which conflicts with the default rest application) you can narrow it down, e.g. for vaadin in my case this is working so far:

```java
@WebServlet(urlPatterns = {"", "/VAADIN/*", "/UIDL/*", "/HEARTBEAT/*"}
```

Thus everything you don't specify more precisely for you main app, will go to the rest app.